# Firebase deploy returns unknown error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy my site to firebase which I have done before but now it is saying "Error: An unknown error occurred. Please contact support." The contents of the firebase-debug.log file follows:

```
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] Platform:     linux
[debug] Node Version: v4.3.0
[debug] Time:         Mon Feb 22 2016 13:58:38 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/firebase/joshweaverspark/token?token=XXX 
[error] 
[error] Error: An unknown error occurred. Please contact support.
[debug] Error Context: {
  "requestOptions": {
    "method": "GET",
    "json": true,
    "url": "https://admin.firebase.com/firebase/joshweaverspark/token?token=-KA3RgJFHuDHz6BHvFQF%7C3b00cd5fc3e1c76f43a26385a3f680c0"
  },
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
      "message": "An unknown error occurred. Please contact support."
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
        "message": "An unknown error occurred. Please contact support."
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "server": "nginx",
      "date": "Mon, 22 Feb 2016 20:58:54 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "content-length": "97",
      "connection": "close",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "admin.firebase.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "admin.firebase.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?token=-KA3RgJFHuDHz6BHvFQF%7C3b00cd5fc3e1c76f43a26385a3f680c0",
        "query": "token=-KA3RgJFHuDHz6BHvFQF%7C3b00cd5fc3e1c76f43a26385a3f680c0",
        "pathname": "/firebase/joshweaverspark/token",
        "path": "/firebase/joshweaverspark/token?token=-KA3RgJFHuDHz6BHvFQF%7C3b00cd5fc3e1c76f43a26385a3f680c0",
        "href": "https://admin.firebase.com/firebase/joshweaverspark/token?token=-KA3RgJFHuDHz6BHvFQF%7C3b00cd5fc3e1c76f43a26385a3f680c0"
      },
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the problem persists, do as the error message tells and contact firebase-support@google.com.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen old question but I ran into this today due to an outdated version of Firebase tools, error was simply `Error: HTTP Error: 410, Unknown Error`. I get warnings in the console to update firebase-functions but not tools. Where's the best place to start debugging this kind of issue? I stumbled across this question but couldn't find any official / unoffical documentation anywhere else.

Comment: We rolled out a change to the deployment process today, which might be causing this. If that's indeed the cause, upgrading the CLI (`npm upgrade --g firebase-tools`) should solve the problem. If not, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

After updating Node.js, i was able to deploy the project. 
You can try the same by updating Node.js:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case upgrading node and npm wasn't enough, but upgrading firebase-tools, fixed the problem

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```